# How do we make sense of the number of particles in the universe in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

This might be a relatively straight forward answer but given the number of particles in the universe is in the region of 10 to the 80, how does this play out in a field-theoretic setting? Can we simply say that there are 10 to the 80 "excited states" of the underlying fields?

Any suggestions of further reading material is greatly appreciated!

Comment: QFT deals more with the interactions of these underlying fields (weak, strong, em). I think in order to make a statement about the particles in the universe we definitely need a GUT, which we do not have yet.

Comment: The number of particles in the universe is not constant so it's a pretty meaningless number.

Comment: I think the $\sim 10^{80}$ is referring the number of baryons (protons and neutrons more or less). You could deal with this in field theory by introducing a chemical potential term coupled to baryon number.

Comment: @octonion that sounds interesting. Please give more details?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus, Made my comment an answer

Comment: @StephenG Baryon number and lepton number are each conserved, however, in the Standard Model (apart from sphaleron interactions which mostly only occur at very high energies similar to those near the Big Bang in time and which still conserves B-L) and those conserved quantum numbers have a very close relationship to the number of fundamental fermionic particles in the universe. I assume that the conservation laws for baryon number and lepton number, however, do not apply to virtual particles. Boson particle numbers, however, are not conserved, as you note.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your $10^{80}$ you quoted is referring to the baryon number of the visible universe. Conserved charges like this can be expressed in terms of the fields in the Lagrangian. For instance the number operator corresponding to a single flavor of fermion $\psi$ is,
$$N=\int d^3x \,\bar{\psi}\gamma^0\psi$$

In principle we could just restrict our consideration of the Hilbert space to those eigenstates of $N$ with eigenvalue $10^{80}$. But it is probably more convenient to instead work in a grand canonical ensemble with some chemical potential $\mu$ that is fixed by the requirement $\langle N\rangle =10^{80}$.

Whenever we have a conserved charge that commutes with the Hamiltonian we can add a chemical potential term to the partition function.

$$Z(\beta,\mu)=\text{Tr}\,e^{-\beta(H-\mu N)}$$

In QFT this becomes a Euclidean path integral and in principle we can use standard QFT techniques to find correlation functions, etc.

For more detail you might want to look at Kapusta and Gale's textbook on finite temperature field theory.

Comment: Does this work with the ordinary formalism of zero-temperature QFT? Can you accommodate for the chemical potential in the Wightman axioms?

Comment: Yes it works with zero-temperature, you just take $\beta$ to go to infinity rather than being finite and periodic. I don't know about how it works with the Wightman axioms. I'm under the impression they are more or less obsolete, but in any case I suspect the lack of covariance of the chemical potential term will be a problem for that framework.